# Why am I receiving "service has been leaked" error in this case?

Tags: android

```
/**********************************************/
// MyActivity extends Activity
/**********************************************/
...
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceThread_Send.class);
sendIntent.putExtra(ServiceThread_Send.KEY_MESSAGE, message);
sendIntent.putExtra(ServiceThread_Send.KEY_RECEIVER_PHONE_NUMBER, receiver);
startService(sendIntent);

// I won't get the error message if I don't call the following method.
finish();

/**********************************************/
// ServiceThread_Send extends IntentService
/**********************************************/

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    ...
    new SendingThread(receiverPhoneNumber, textMessage, this).start();
}

/**********************************************/
// SendingThread extends Thread
/**********************************************/
public void run()
{
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE|Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT);
}
```

And here is what I get:

> ServiceThread_Send has leaked ServiceConnection SendingThread$1@419a18d0 that was originally bound here

1. Why am I getting this error.
2. Why am I told I'm leaking a 'thread'? Isn't this error specific to
   'services'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Because I have used an IntentService, it does its job and then calls selfStop() on itself. As a result, any service originally bound there, is leaked. What I did, was to change:

```
    bindService(...);
```

To this:

```
    getApplicationContext.bindService(...);
```

and everything works like a charm. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making it as an IntentService, what is the need to start another thread.
Intent service already works in worker thread so no need to start another thread there.
Just do you work, when you get intent in `onHandleIntent` and then intent service would call `stopSelf` by its own.

Comment: That's because IntentService responses to requests ONE AFTER ANOTHER and this is not what I want. I want to process all the requests simultaneously. Please correct me if I'm wrong.